# Javascript - accessing array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this code:

```
function make_buttons (id) {
    var operators = [["*","multiply"],["/","divide"],["+","add"],["-","divide"],["=","calc_it"]]
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = 'text'; input.id = 'inp';
        parent.appendChild(input);
        for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
            var btn = document.createElement ("button");
            btn.innerHTML = i;
            btn.id = i;
            parent.appendChild(btn);
            (function(index) {btn.onclick = function() {input.value += index;}})(i);
        }
    for (var j = 0; j < operators.length; j++) {

        var operators[j][1] = document.createElement ("button");


    };
```

So I have an array wich has array inside of it. Now I want to set the name of the variable to be operator name inside of the array. In current case it should be 'multiply'.

But it gives me a syntax error when doing this.

What I want to achieve is this :

```
var multiply = document.createElement ("button");
        multiply.innerHTML = "*";
        multiply.id = "*";
        parent.appendChild(multiply);
        multiply.onclick = function () {input.value += '*';};
        var divide = document.createElement ("button");
        divide.innerHTML = "/";
        divide.id = "/";
        parent.appendChild(divide);
        var add = document.createElement ("button");
        add.innerHTML = "+";
        add.id = "+";
        parent.appendChild(add);
        var substract = document.createElement ("button");
        substract.innerHTML = "-";
        substract.id = "-";
        parent.appendChild(substract);
```

But with the array, so that there is less code written and also less repetitiveness.

Comment: Why not use a collection to ease confusion? `[{operator:'*',name:'multiply',{operator:'/',name:'divide'}...]`

Comment: And I make the variable have the operator name like this?   var operators.name[0] =   ?    the .name part gets highlighted in the editor like a function and console gives a syntax error about the "."

Comment: More like that `operators[i].name`